# Ajax loading tabs not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i,m trying to make a loading tabs with jquery & ajax, I have "page-1.html, page-2.html, page-3.html, page-4.html, page-5.html", the "page-1.html" is the main page that I want to display it first, but i faced a problem that the page stops loading and the tabs content not shown, only the loading class shows `<div class=\"loading\"></div>`
here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Tabs (getFile)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: getFile,
        beforeSend: function (){
            $(".PagesContent").html("<div class=\"loading\"></div>");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $(".PagesContent").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function (){

    Tabs ("page-1.html")

    $(".pages ul > li").click(function (){
        $(".pages ul > li").removeAttr("class");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.loading{
    background-image:url('images/loading.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    margin:15px auto;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="pages">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supplies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Set Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--End pages-->      
    <div class="PagesContent"></div><!--End Pages Contents-->

</body>
</html>
```

why is that wrong? the page `page-1.html` is not shown! Only the loading img is shown.

Comment: can you check the browser console for any errors

Comment: The `url: getfile` should be `url: getFile`

Comment: it's already getFile , sorry typing error , i still have the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know for sure that your timing is right, you could do this (you need jQuery 1.5 or newer)

```
function Tabs (getFile)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: getFile,
        beforeSend: function (){
            $(".PagesContent").html("<div class=\"loading\"></div>");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function (){

    $.when(Tabs("page-1.html"))
        .done(function () {
            $(".PagesContent").html(data);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            $(".PagesContent").html("<span class='error'>Failed to load tab.</span>");
        })

    $(".pages ul > li").click(function (){
        $(".pages ul > li").removeAttr("class");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });

});
```

As said before; does your browser return any errors (in the console)?

Comment: nothing happened , only the class "loading" <div class=\"loading\"></div> is shown

Comment: Check your server reply with the network tab of the Web Inspector. People can only help you if you provide enough information.